# How to implement the following query in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I have a query like this

```
SELECT
  tableA.field1,
  SUM(tableB.field4) AS the_sum
FROM
  tableA 
  LEFT JOIN tableB ON tableA.field1 = tableB.field2
WHERE
  /* IN() for multiple possible vals. Use = if only 1 val needed
     and then the GROUP BY is unnecessary */
  tableA.field1 IN ('val1','val2',val3')
GROUP BY tableA.field1
```

how to implement the following query in hibernate?. and also i need to return the value as the objects of the curresponding tables. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query would be almost identical:

```
select a.field1, sum(b.field4) as the_sum
from EntityA a left join a.b
where a.field1 in ('val1', 'val2', 'val3')
group by a.field1
```

That is assuming that there is an association from EntityA to EntityB using a.field1 as a foreign key to b.field2 (or vice-versa). If you don't have such an association, it's impossible. left joins are only possible with associations.